# Using external SQLite database with SwiftUI

Tags: sqlite, swiftui

I am writing a SwiftUI app that needs to read an external SQLite database. I just need to open the database, query the database, copy values into an array and close the database. Then I need to load the text from one variable in the array to the buttons in a view. I am using the SQLite.swift library but I'm not sure how to do it.

I don't have any code yet but I have loaded the SQLite.swift package and just need to write my DatabaseHelper class and then run it when the View is opened. If anyone can help please reply! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that I haven't actually done this, but will have to in the near future. You are going to have to accept the fact that you need to take baby steps and throw out half your work, perhaps multiple times, until you get a satisfactory solution.

I would start by opening your db outside swiftui, probably in the app delegate class. Then stick all your values into the environment object and attach that to your content view

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(your_stuff_here)
```

Down in Swiftui you can extract the details from the environment object and add them to your button.

That should at least get you going.